# zsh run command multiple times for results of regular expression

Tags: regex, zsh

I would like to run a command multiple time, depending on the results of my regular expression in zsh.

This is an example of what I want the box to do:

- ping -c 1 10.0.0.44
- ping -c 1 10.0.0.45
- ping -c 1 10.0.0.46

Try1: `ping -c 1 '10.0.0.4[4-6]'` gives me `ping: 10.0.0.4[4-6]: Name or service not known`

Try2: `ping -c 1 10.0.0.4{4..6}` only pings 10.0.0.46

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: `ping` can only process 1 address, you need to do `for` loop or `xargs` or any other tools to invoke ping multiple times

Comment: I want zsh to do the expansion, not ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take:

```sh
% eval 'ping -c1 10.0.0.4'{4..6}';'  # needs ; to separate the commands
% for ip in 10.0.0.4{4..6}; do ping -c1 $ip; done
```

Both will result in the same output.

In a script or function, I would generally prefer the latter, since it's marginally faster and enables the shell to detect syntax errors when parsing, but the former is faster to type.